# How do I log into remote host using private ssh key with user that is different from the user that is running the script?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am running an Ansible script that attempts to log into the remote host via ssh using rsa keys. The problem is that the user that is running Ansible script (on WSL Windows machine) is different from the user that supposes to log into the remote host. The script looks like this:

```yaml
- hosts: servers_test
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: "remote_user"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: "remote_user"
    ansible_become_password: "remote_user_pass"
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "/home/remote_user/.ssh/id_rsa"
  tasks:
    - name: Gather facts from remote_host
      setup:
```

The problem is that ssh connection in Ansible is done by `ssh` command which requires private key to have permission 0600. So when I run the script the following error is thrown

```
<172.27.254.109> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/remote_user/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="remote_user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/local_user/.ansible/cp/0eddb9ee6d"' 172.27.254.109 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~remote_user && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.27.254.109> (255, b'', b'no such identity: /home/remote_user/.ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied\r\nremote_user@172.27.254.109: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
fatal: [172.27.254.109]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: /home/remote_user/.ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied\r\nremote_user@172.27.254.109: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

So my understanding is that local_user (the one who is running the script) has no access to the private key of remote_user. That is understandable especially if ownership of the key is set to remote_user:remote_user and permissions set to 0600. The question is what to do so the Ansible script as shown above can successfully access private ssh key and log into remote host.

Comment: Run `ansible-playbook` directly as `remote_user` on the local machine or `chown` the key so that `local_user` can access it.